# what's the best JS library for Audio Time Stretching?

Tags: audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am looking for audio time stretching library with the best quality for javascript.
Thanks for you help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do time streching audio playback using javascript in 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791472/how-to-do-time-streching-audio-playback-using-javascript-in-2019)

Comment: _"I am looking for..."_  Is Google not working for you? That should be your research point. We later answer questions about the code you wrote (and help with how it's not working).