# create html <audio> element from Tone.js object

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, tone.js

I am using Tone.js to modify sounds:

```
audio_url = "/sounds/damncoolbeats.m4a"
player = new Tone.Player(audio_url)
modified_player = <some Tone.js modifications to player>
```

To play the modified sound I would like to use a web audio element so that I can make use of audio.currentTime and eventlisteners to 'play' 'pause' and 'timeupdate' (which I can't seem to do with Tone.js).

The only way I managed to create an audio element so far is by loading from an url:

```
audio = new Audio(audio_url)
```

My current hacky solution is to load the original url twice, once in Tone.js and once as web audio, then I play both players simultaneously while keeping the web audio volume at zero. Loading the same http resource twice really messes with my website speed though...

Is there a way to create the web audio element from a Tone.js object?

```
audio = new Audio(modified_player) //does not work
audio = new Audio(modified_player.buffer) //does not work
audio = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(modified_player.buffer)) //does not work
```

Comment: Have you figured this one out yet?

Comment: No... I still think it should be possible though as Tone.js is built on top of the web audio API. Please let me know if you figure something out.

Comment: I ended up just doing the conversion on the back end on asp.net...i mostly was just doing a pitch change for a karaoke app

Comment: wish you got the answer for this.

Comment: Still no luck, sorry. I contacted the author of Tone.js but got no reply either... Please let me know if you find out how to do this!